# Data structure supporting efficient ranged filter + group + sort by aggregate value + paginate

Tags: database, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

Consider a collection of "sale" records with these fields:

- Date
- Seller
- Revenue

These records are immutable and created in chronological order.

Now, consider a paginated query for a given date range, grouped by seller, ordered by total revenue per seller, like this:

```
Top sellers between [date] and [date] - Page 1

1. Alice   $999
2. Bob     $888
3. Chuck   $777
...
```

What sort of data structure(s)/algorithms could do this efficiently, assuming:

- Very many unique sellers
- Very many records per seller
- Very many pages of results (no sequential operations on results outside the requested page)
- Date ranges are entirely variable and arbitrary

I understand how to get total revenue without grouping: an ordered tree structure, keyed on the date, with total revenue stored at each intermediate node.

Grouping without a date range could similarly use a tree keyed on seller, with revenue and number of unique sellers at each node.

But the combined filtering and grouping, I can't quite figure out.

For bonus points, are there any off-the-shelf databases that can do this? And support custom aggregation logic e.g. map/reduce?

Comment: You should state explicitly whether your database is static. If not, then are records added in sorted order by date?

Comment: Also it might be interesting if you can tell anything about distribution of results: are they expected to be close to each other?
It is easy to iterate over all sellers, fetch data for each of them in logarithmic time, then sort the results. Am I right that you want a faster solution, that takes time sublinear of "very many" amounts?

Comment: Ah yes, I neglected to mention that records are immutable and created in chronological order.

Comment: And yes, there are too many unique sellers to iterate over all of them in any way for a single query. Page 1000 may have sellers ranked 10,001 to 10,100, so I have to generate that page without scanning over the 10,000 prior sellers.